# Php contact form not being recieved

Tags: php, forms, contacts

Downloaded a template for a basic bootstrap site today, after customizing it and uploading to my host I realized that the contact form does not send the email although it says it has been sent.

I have never done any php coding nor do I know the language any help is appreciated!

Here is the code for the php

```
    <?php
// Check for empty fields
if(empty($_POST['name'])        ||
   empty($_POST['email'])       ||
   empty($_POST['phone'])       ||
   empty($_POST['message']) ||
   !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
   {
    echo "No arguments Provided!";
    return false;
   }

$name = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
$email_address = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']));
$phone = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['phone']));
$message = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']));

// Create the email and send the message
$to = 'Jonathan@slickpixeldesigns.com'; // Add your email address inbetween the '' replacing yourname@yourdomain.com - This is where the form will send a message to.
$email_subject = "Website Contact Form:  $name";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from your website contact form.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\nName: $name\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\nPhone: $phone\n\nMessage:\n$message";
$headers = "From: noreply@yourdomain.com\n"; // This is the email address the generated message will be from. We recommend using something like noreply@yourdomain.com.
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address"; 
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;            
?>
```

Comment: Maybe you don't have a mail server configured on your server host.

Comment: are you actually passing your contact form details to this php page on the form submit and are the input names the same as in this page?

Comment: That may actually be my issue, Upon looking at the html I dont see any links to the php